# Remember modes for files without extensions

Tags: major-mode

I've started editing a lot of files that have no extensions, but are still in a major mode format.

I'm the only Emacs user on the team, and I don't want to make it a painfully obvious that my editor needs *special* stuff. I would like to avoid changing the codebase.

- I can't change the filename
- I can't use special Emacs comments

I would like Emacs to remember whatever mode I put the file manually in last (with, say <kbd>M-x</kbd> `conf-mode`) and automatically activate that mode when I visit it again.

I use `savehist-mode` to handle persistence.

Can I do this painlessly?

Comment: If that's the file you can edit, typically you can add a first line with a comment: `# -*- mode: conf -*-`, and that would tip Emacs off to use `conf-mode`. If there are few of them, and you can match them via regular expression, you can add the regexp to `automode-alist`.

Comment: @wvxvw one of my limitations is that "_I can't use special Emacs comments_".

Comment: Ouch, sorry, I don't understand how I've missed that. Also, it's `auto-mode-alist`, my bad.

Comment: Clearly the correct answer here is to get the rest of your team to use Emacs. Any other answer is just a workaround.

Answer (score 13):

There are a number of ways to identify the major mode for a file that don't rely on an extension, see [Choosing File Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html#Choosing-Modes) in the manual.

Depending on the kinds of files you are dealing with, perhaps you could use the `magic-mode-alist`. Also note that `auto-mode-alist` is not limited to matching extensions: you can match any part of the file name or path.

If the files you are dealing with are not consistent enough for those mechanisms, one option is to add `auto-mode-alist` entries that match the entire file name, or match the root path of some project and call a custom function to match names to modes.

If all the files in a given directory are of the same type you could also use a directory-local variable to set the mode. Directory variables can be set in your init file rather than in a .dir-locals  file -- see [Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables) for details.

*Update*

Here's a quick attempt at managing your own alist of absolute file names and major-modes.

```el
(defvar my-custom-mode-alist '())
(defvar my-custom-mode-alist-file (expand-file-name "custom-file-assoc" user-emacs-directory))

;; command to save the file->mode association of the current buffer
(defun save-file-mode-association ()
  (interactive)
  (when buffer-file-name
    (add-to-list 'my-custom-mode-alist (cons buffer-file-name major-mode))
    (write-custom-mode-alist my-custom-mode-alist-file)))

(defun write-custom-mode-alist (file)
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Custom File Assocations*")
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (pp my-custom-mode-alist (current-buffer))
    (condition-case nil
        (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file)
      (file-error (message "Can't write %s" file)))
    (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
    (message "Wrote custom file associations to file %s" file)))

(defun load-custom-mode-alist (file)
  (when (file-exists-p file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (let ((enable-local-variables nil))
          (find-file-noselect file))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (setq my-custom-mode-alist (read (current-buffer)))
      (setq auto-mode-alist (append auto-mode-alist my-custom-mode-alist))
      (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))))

;; Load any custom file associations and add them to auto-mode-alist
(load-custom-mode-alist my-custom-mode-alist-file)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the files are pretty loosely formatted, and they have very generic file names. Thanks for pointing out the specifics of `auto-mode-alist`, though. I'll probably keep `magic-mode-alist` in the back of my mind for something in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The following, based on Glucas' advice seems to work perfectly.

```el
(defvar file-name-mode-alist '())
;; other stuff here, of course
(setq savehist-additional-variables '(file-name-mode-alist))
(savehist-mode +1)
(setq auto-mode-alist (append auto-mode-alist file-name-mode-alist))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (when (and
            buffer-file-name
            (not
              (file-name-extension
                buffer-file-name)))
       (setq file-name-mode-alist
        (cons
          (cons buffer-file-name major-mode)
          file-name-mode-alist))
      (setq auto-mode-alist
        (append auto-mode-alist
          (list (cons buffer-file-name major-mode)))))))
```

Comment: Nice. A more elegant solution than the one I hacked together. :-)